# Loosely embedding $\ell_\infty$ in $\ell_2$.

Tags: normed-spaces

Fix $n$ and $t$. I want a constant $C$ and a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with the following properties. ($m$ can be arbitrary.)

- If $\|x-y\|_\infty \leq 1$, then $\|f(x)-f(y)\|_2 \leq 1$.
- If $\|f(x)-f(y)\|_2 \leq C\sqrt{m}$, then $\|x-y\|_\infty \leq t$.

If $f(x)=x/\sqrt{n}$ is the scaled identify function ($m=n$), then $C=t/n$ suffices for the above. However, I want this to hold for larger $C$. Ideally, I want this to hold for $C \approx t$. Is this possible?

**Given $n$ and $t$, what is the largest value of $C$ for which such a function $f$ exists?**

Essentially I am asking for a very loose embedding of $\ell_\infty$ into $\ell_2$. I'm hoping that someone has seen something similar and can point me in the right direction. (e.g. tell me the right keywords to google.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: looking at $\displaystyle C_{max} = \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|x\|_\infty = 1} \|x\|_2$ which depends only on $n$, and in the same way to $\displaystyle  C_{min} = \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|x\|_\infty = 1} \|x\|_2$ might be useful (for bounding $\frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2}$ above and below)

Comment: _coarse embedding_ is the most similar term that I know.